# Powershell script using global admin creds with MFA

Tags: powershell, authentication, office365, powershell-3.0

Is it possible to connect to Office365 services with Powershell with a global admin credentials that has MFA enabled by using the "application" password ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not. Here are a couple of articles that should clarify what you are asking for.

> We've been able to get our Office 365 Admin accounts with MFA enabled
>   working with Powershell for Exchange Online, Skype for Business
>   etc.....
>   with some caveats:
>
> • This requires an Azure AD Premium, Enterprise Mobility Suite or Azure
>   Multi-Factor Authentication subscription 
>   • The admin account must be a
>   cloud only account (will not work for federated accounts)
>
> https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Identity-Authentication/Authenticating-to-O365-using-Powershell-and-MFA/m-p/28580#M166
>
> First Steps: Securing Office 365 Administrator Accounts with
>   Multi-Factor Authentication
>
> When you sign up a new Office 365 tenant a Global Admin account is
>   created for you. This Global Admin account, and any other admin
>   accounts you create later on, are highly privileged, powerful accounts
>   that need to be protected from compromise.
>
> https://practical365.com/security/securing-office-365-administrator-accounts-multi-factor-authentication